The son of a professor's father is talking to the father of the professor's son but the professor does not take part in the conversation. Can this be?
The son of a professor's father is talking to the father of the professor's son, but the professor does not take part in the conversation.  Is this possible?
Attribution:  Mathematical Circles (Russian Experience)
Clarification of the phrase, “the professor does not take part in the conversation”:
This means the professor is not one of the two people that are talking.  Maybe the professor is not there or is silent.

Why wouldn't this be possible? Because the professor would likely say something at some point?

@noedne You have to determine if it is possible that the professor is NOT talking given the information provided in the question.

what a long title


 It's possible. Here is the relationship: 



Almost, but I'm pretty sure that the two who are talking are those on the very left and very right of your diagram...

@Stiv You're RIGHT!!

Being corrected by this gentleman @Stiv, I updated the diagram.

Thanks. In my capacity as a gentleman I can now +1 this answer :)

rot13(gur fba pbhyq nyfb unir gjb snguref ohg znlor n ehffvna chmmyr jbhyqa'g pbafvqre gung na bcgvba...)

@Jafe Indeed. In fact, I considered mentioning that in my answer but left it as the 'classic solution' to problems of this type for simplicity, although admittedly for completeness it should probably be included... EDIT: I have added it for completeness, thanks.

The traditional answer to logic questions of this type is to reason that the professor...

 ...is female. The conversation is happening between her brother (the son of [this] professor's father) and her husband/partner (the father of the professor's son). She, however, is elsewhere.

However, as @Jafe rightly points out in a comment on the other answer...

 ...in modern society you do not need to be female to have a child in a relationship with a man. In which case, there is no need to bring sex or gender into the puzzle at all: The conversation is simply happening between the professor's brother (the son of [this] professor's father) and the professor's husband/partner (the father of the professor's son). The professor, however, is elsewhere.


@Will.Octagon.Gibson I disagree. If it said 'the only son' then yes, for sure. But you can refer to any son as 'the son' in the same way as you can refer to any apple as 'the apple' if it's the one you're talking about. Take Luke 3 in the Bible for example: "...the son of Judah, the son of Jacob..." - Jacob is renowned for having 12 sons, yet still here Judah is described as the son!

@MindwinRememberMonica Not totally sure who you think is 'grandstanding' here... And if the comment you are referring to as not existing is the one I've linked to in my answer, note that it is written in rot13.

An entirely different answer is possible if we consider "father" to mean "priest".
In that case, a priest and the priest's son are talking.
The priest is called Father both by a professor and the professor's son.

out of the box, awesome.

Another option not brought up in the other answers is that

 the professor's son is adopted. In that case, the professor's brother would be talking to the son's biological father (or perhaps the professor is the biological father, and the brother is talking to the son's adoptive father).



 The professor has a brother, and is a married lady (or is a married gay man). The professor’s brother is talking to their brother-in-law.


What does "taking part in the conversation" mean? Professor's brother is talking to him, but he does not respond and pretends not to hear. Happens in some families...
Or the professor is dead and his brother is talking to him saying how much he will be missed etc...

I have updated my question.  I hope it makes sense now.

@Will.Octagon.Gibson yes, now my answer fits the question perfectly :-)
